# Was Cad Bane a Chiss?

Tags: star-wars

So with the release of the 2017 novel *Thrawn* and with Grand Admiral Thrawn becoming a villain on the Rebels animated Series we now know that the Chiss Acendancy is Canon. Now anyone who knows about the Chiss knows that they have Blue Skin with glowing red eyes. The best example of which would be the Grand Admiral himself.

[image]

However I'm wondering if the bounty hunter Cad Bane from the Clone Wars animated series was also a Chiss since he has the same blue skin and red glowing eyes:

[image]

The reason I think that he is Chiss and not some other species with similar features is because in the novel *Thrawn* nobody can figure out what species Thrawn is by looking at him. Nobody had really seen a Chiss before due to their isolationism and hiding in the Unknown Regions. I'm wondering if his wouldn't also be the case with Cad Bane. So is he a Chiss and if not what species is he?

Comment: If he is Chiss, what happened to his nose? Really the whole facial structure is different.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Cad Bane is a Duros

This is confirmed on [his entry](http://www.starwars.com/databank/cad-bane) in the official Databank (emphasis mine):

> A ruthless bounty hunter **from the planet Duro**, Cad Bane was the preeminent blaster-for-hire in the galaxy at the time of the Clone Wars.

[image]

There's really no reason to suspect a connection between the two races:

- [Duro](http://www.starwars.com/databank/duro) is a Core World, which puts it in the same galactic neighbourhood as Coruscant and Alderaan; that's about as far from the Unknown Regions as you can get
- Despite some superficial similarities, they really appear quite different; Duros lack noses, lips, [auricles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auricle_(anatomy)), hair, and visible [irises](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_(anatomy)) and pupils, all of which (except lips, arguably) Thrawn definitely has:

  [image]

  To vastly oversimplify, Duros look like humans wearing full head masks, while Chiss look like humans wearing facepaint and contact lenses

In the novel *Thrawn*, people unfamiliar with Thrawn's background tend to assume that he's a [Pantoran](http://www.starwars.com/databank/pantoran) with an eye condition, which is a much closer match than the Duros.

Comment: Beat me by 10 seconds

Comment: When it comes to pupils. By the time Clone Wars was made all artwork for a Chiss had solid glowing red eyes with no pupils. That change didn't come around until after the Disney takeover and we didn't see it until Thrawn was an actual character on Rebels.

Comment: One minor quibble, the Core Worlds are comparatively close to the edge of the Unknown Regions. Duro and Csilla still aren't particularly close but Ryloth in the Outer Rim is more than twice as far from Csilla as Duro is.

Comment: To be honest I hadn't rewatched the clone wars for a while before asking the question. All I remembered about Cad Bane was the skin and eyes

Answer (score 2):

No.  According to Wookieepedia, we was a Durosian.

http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cad_Bane

Answer (score -1):

On top of being a total badass, Cad Bane is a Duros. They're the Star Wars version of the "grays" from pop culture. They can be traced all the way back to A New Hope in the famous cantina scene that gave rise to so many core Star Wars species back in the earliest days of the IP's growth. Unlike the Chiss, Duros evolved independently from humans, thus the unusual head shape and missing familiar facial features. Although, like the Chiss, they're quite cool! The Duros were one of the first (if not the first) to explore the core worlds beyond their home planet, probably due to the fact that they can be seen wearing what appear to be space/flight suits in that Episode 4 scene.

Comment: Your answer would benefit greatly if you also provided sources and references.